# Texstudio shortcuts not working after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, shortcut

after the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. I have a problem with my Texstudio. I used to compile with the shortcut F6, but after the upgrade it doesn't work anymore (shortcuts in other programs are doing fine).

Thanks in advance,
Luca

Comment: Can you try if you can set it manually? `preferences->Shortcuts->Tools->Compile`? Double click on the entry in the "Current shortcut" column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known (and unfortunately, by now, rather long-standing) issue involving Qt5 (version 5 of [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)), the graphical toolkit used to create TeXStudio’s user interface).
It has come up several times in [TeXStudio’s bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/) and other places; for example:

- [#1467 (Shortcuts does not work after upgrade to 2.10)](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1467/)
- [#1495 (Keyboard shortcut for segment preview doesn't work)](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1495/)
- [#1732 (Some shortcuts are not working, when some others do)](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1732/)
- And, most relevant to your question in particular: [#1853 (Shortcuts do not work on Ubuntu 16.04)](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1853/)

The solution is to install a version of TeXStudio that is built against the previous version, Qt4.
Unfortunately, such a version is not available in Ubuntu’s default repositories.
Instead, you can go to [TeXStudio’s official download page](http://www.texstudio.org/#download) and choose a link that says “QT 4”.

Answer (score 13):

I found this solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786280/texmaker-shortcuts-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04), it works fine for TeXStudio: Edit the file

```
/usr/share/applications/texstudio.desktop
```

and change the line

```
Exec=texstudio %F
```

to

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texstudio %F
```

NOTE: Remember to edit the file again after upgrade to version 2.12.2, released Jan 24, 2017.

NOTE (Jul 25, 2017): TeXStudio released yesterday: TeXstudio 2.12.6 (hg 6631:16db084dae24). Using Qt Version 5.5.1, compiled with Qt 5.5.1 R, works fine without any edit of file `/usr/share/applications/texstudio.desktop`. The nightmare is over!!!

Comment: It works as a charm!

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: any chance of doing this without sudo access?

Comment: @E.P., the superuser `root` is the owner of `/usr` directory, so you need her/his credentials in order to modify `texstudio.desktop` file.

Comment: @tatojo I found it later - this also works by copying that file to `~/.local/share/applications/` and modifying that copy.

Answer (score 4):

This is bug in Qt-5 package. Remove the "appmenu-qt5" package to get the shortcuts working again.

```
                   sudo apt remove appmenu-qt5
```

This seems to induce some changes in the appearance of menu buttons in TexStudio, but the shortcuts are enabled.

Comment: This solution worked for me on `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 64-bit` with qt5 compiled Texstudio.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution to what @Socob suggested might be (for Ubuntu 16.04) to navigate to the applications folder (/usr/share/applications) as sudo, right-click on 'texstudio' and select 'Properties'. 
Change the 'texstudio %F' to 'env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texstudio %F'. At least, that did it for me. I am not aware of any downsides to this.

EDIT: As pointed out by @Orion in the comment, the HUD stops working when using this solution. This has never been an inconvenience to me, since I never use the HUD, but as always, it's good to be aware of the possible downsides.

Comment: Worked for me 16.04 (TeXstudio 2.11.2 Using Qt Version 5.5.1, compiled with Qt 5.4.2 R). This seems to disable the [Heads Up Display (HUD)](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-hud-intro.html) for TexStudio menus.

Comment: Good find @Orion I added this in an edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround (worked for me) is to add the menu command to the toolbar (from Configure/Toolbars), then the assigned keyboard shortcut could work.