# Texstudio Ctrl+Alt+Space shortcut not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu, shortcut

I'm experiencing a similar problem to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326678/texstudio-shortcuts-not-working-after-upgrade-to-16-04).  Basically, Texstudio (tested versions 2.12.6 and 2.12.8) doesn't recognize the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.  Other combinations seem to work.

The [solution of creating the environment variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349631/7561) is not working, and it seems the problem is solved (except for not working on Ubuntu 18.04).

I [asked the developers](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/217) and seems that it is working as intended in Lubuntu, but not in Ubuntu.

I also checked the keyboard shortcuts on my system (Activities->Keyboard->Shortcuts) and there is no binding there.

How can I make the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> work under Ubuntu 18.04?

#### Details of System

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.2

$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME (both on VirtualBox with two keyboard layouts, switced by Super+Space). Also check shorcuts interference with `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "alt.*ctrl\|ctrl.*alt"`.

Comment: Strange.  There are no conflicts: `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Alt>Print' org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R'`

Also, I'm using an upgrade version from 17.10, not sure if that is an issue.  

Another thing that I noticed trying to debug is that the key combination is not shown when typing on `Language tooltip -> Show Keyboard Layout` screen.

Comment: @N0rbert any other way to check which program may be grabbing the key combination?

Comment: @ adn I do not know such ways.

Comment: You're using Ctrl+Alt+Space for `\begin{...}` completion? Why not use Ctrl+E which also does `\end{}` at the same time?

Comment: I'm using that now.  But I used to use the completion when writing some words.  For instance, I wrote `ite` and then hit Ctrl+Alt+Space and got the `itemize` environment all together.  I'm not sure what part of the 18.04 is breaking the functionality.  I have another system with 18.04 and the same thing happens.

Comment: I see, okay. Honestly, this reads to me like a Ubuntu problem, I'm not quite sure how much we (the TeX community) can help here, even with the bounty. I don't have Ubuntu myself, so I can't reproduce the problem. Does changing it to a different keyboard shortcut not work / is it not an option?

Comment: `Ubuntu 16.04.5` here with TeXstudio. `ctrl+alt+space` works fine for me. I agree with @Troy though, why not `ctrl+e` or Options > Configure TeXstudio > Completion > "Automatically start completer when typing LaTeX-Commands"?

Comment: @adn have you looked at [this answer to check keybindinggs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62254/24024)? The steps at the very bottom should do the trick and tell you what is grabbing the keybinding. As I suspect a keybinding/software issue I am not really sure how this got ever migrated here.

Comment: @ted thanks for the pointers.  I tested them with no luck.  I will continue debugging in that path.  Jesse Knight I would prefer to use the other combination if possible.  For now I'm switching it, but is not ideal.

Comment: @adn you could try on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) if you havenot done that yet, but there seem more open questions about keybindings than succesfully resolved ones